# How to assign DataTable to SQLDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, sqldatasource

I have bind my `GridView` with `SQLDataSource` and it is working fine. Now I have a method (this method is from a dll, so I can't alter it) which returns `DataTable` and I have to assign this `DataTable` to `SQLDataSource`.

I am looking for something like this

```
SQLDataSource1.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

I know there is no `DataSource` property in `SQLDataSource`, but I need similar kind of functionality.

If I set `GridView1.DataSource = MyDataTable;` then I loose all functionality of SQLDataSource like sorting, updating etc.

Code example will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to assign the table to the SqlDataSource at all? Can't you use the table as DataSource for the GridView directly?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter : I have updated my question. If I can set DataSource of SQLDataSource then all other functionality is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change from SqlDataSource to ObjectDataSource. That will allow you to call your method and still do paging

You can read more on [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.enablepaging.aspx) and [an more here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13963/Implement-Paging-using-ObjectDataSource-with-GridV)

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
    SelectCountMethod="GetXXXMethodCount" //a method that return total number of records
    EnablePaging="true" 
    TypeName="YourBLLFullClassName" 
    SelectMethod="GetXXXMethod"
    MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRows"
    StartRowIndexParameterName="startRows"
    ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
    runat="server">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Yes this is a option, but if I can set DataSource of SQLDataSource then all other functionality is ready. If I can keep `SQLDataSource` then it will be good.

Comment: I think ObjectDataSource is better than SQLDataSource as you can have a central BLL method that all ObjectDataSource can use, which can still be used by other part of your code. SQLDataSource on the other hand has SQL written in the Markup which not portable and is only useful to that page alone

Comment: Are you sure that I can still use all functionality of SQLDataSource without any changes in code?

Comment: Yes. Your SQL will go away and data will be coming from your method. The maxRows and startRows needs to be taken care of. Read those links.